# JPA Saving wrong date in MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, date, jpa, jodatime

I have a table in my MySQL database that has a date column:

```
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| type              | varchar(50)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| expiration        | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
```

I'm using MySQL with JPA to save dates. I have a feature that the user can select a final date range and it will get all the dates.

Check out this code (with a bunch of SYSOs) to try to see whats going on...

```
@Override
    protected DateTime nextReference(DateTime reference) {
        System.out.println("Reference: " + reference.toString("dd-MM-YYYY"));
        DateTime plus = reference.plusMonths(1);
        System.out.println("One month from now: " + plus.toString("dd-MM-YYYY"));

        DateTime result = plus.withDayOfMonth(reference.getDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println("Final: " + result.toString("dd-MM-YYYY"));

        return result;
    }
```

This part, the result was fine:

```
Reference: 10-01-2017
One month from now: 10-02-2017
Final: 10-02-2017
Reference: 10-02-2017
One month from now: 10-03-2017
Final: 10-03-2017
Reference: 10-03-2017
One month from now: 10-04-2017
Final: 10-04-2017
Reference: 10-04-2017
One month from now: 10-05-2017
Final: 10-05-2017
Reference: 10-05-2017
One month from now: 10-06-2017
Final: 10-06-2017
Reference: 10-06-2017
One month from now: 10-07-2017
Final: 10-07-2017
Reference: 10-07-2017
One month from now: 10-08-2017
Final: 10-08-2017
Reference: 10-08-2017
One month from now: 10-09-2017
Final: 10-09-2017
Reference: 10-09-2017
One month from now: 10-10-2017
Final: 10-10-2017
Reference: 10-10-2017
One month from now: 10-11-2017
Final: 10-11-2017
Reference: 10-11-2017
One month from now: 10-12-2017
Final: 10-12-2017
Reference: 10-12-2017
One month from now: 10-01-2018
Final: 10-01-2018
```

Ok, now lets move to the save part:

```
@Transactional
private void saveTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions) {
    for (Transaction t : transactions) {
        System.out.println("Saving: " + t.getExpiration().toString("dd-MM-YYYY"));
        Transaction saved = dao.save(t);
        System.out.println("Saved: " + saved.getExpiration().toString("dd-MM-YYYY"));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I put some lines to debug this also.... Before I continue with the output, check out the DAO:

```
public T save(T entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    return entity;
}
```

No big deal right... The output:

```
Saving: 10-02-2017
Saved: 10-02-2017
Saving: 10-03-2017
Saved: 10-03-2017
Saving: 10-04-2017
Saved: 10-04-2017
Saving: 10-05-2017
Saved: 10-05-2017
Saving: 10-06-2017
Saved: 10-06-2017
Saving: 10-07-2017
Saved: 10-07-2017
Saving: 10-08-2017
Saved: 10-08-2017
Saving: 10-09-2017
Saved: 10-09-2017
Saving: 10-10-2017
Saved: 10-10-2017
Saving: 10-11-2017
Saved: 10-11-2017
Saving: 10-12-2017
Saved: 10-12-2017
```

As you can see... It should be fine right? Everything on the 10th.

Before I continue again, check the model, and the converter:

```
    //Attribute
    @Convert(converter = JpaDateConverter.class)
    private DateTime expiration;

//Converter

public class JpaDateConverter implements AttributeConverter<DateTime, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(DateTime objectValue) {
        return objectValue == null ? null : new Date(objectValue.getMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public DateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Date dataValue) {
        return dataValue == null ? null : new DateTime(dataValue);
    }

}
```

Now look at my database:

```
mysql> select expiration from tb_transaction where notes = 3 and year(expiration
) = 2017;
+------------+
| expiration |
+------------+
| 2017-01-10 |
| 2017-02-10 |
| 2017-03-09 |
| 2017-04-09 |
| 2017-05-09 |
| 2017-06-09 |
| 2017-07-09 |
| 2017-08-09 |
| 2017-09-09 |
| 2017-10-09 |
| 2017-11-10 |
| 2017-12-10 |
+------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For some, wierd, mystic reason, some dates where saved on the 9ths instead of the 10th !!

No Warnings, no Errors on MySQL driver or nothing.

Please HELP  guys!

**EDIT** Transaction Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_transaction")
public class Transaction implements Cloneable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(STRING)
    private TransactionType type;

    @Convert(converter = JpaDateConverter.class)
    private DateTime expiration;
```

Comment: add your  Transaction mapping class with date imports

Comment: It's probably because of DST.  DST occurs in March and November, notice your dates change at those times.

Comment: Rick do you know any workaround?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski I updated the question. Was that what you meant?

Comment: In your converter class, there has to be a way to convert from `DateTime` to `Date` by just taking the `Date` portion of `DateTime` and ignoring the `Time`.  Calling `getMillis()` is causing the DST issue.

Comment: I experimented the way you described and it works as expected. I tried on Oracle 11g and MySQL with the same result.

Comment: I think @RickS is right, the getMillis() is causing the DST issue. Could you transform your comment in an answer please ?

Comment: @ujulu did you use the converter?

Comment: Yes, I used both the `@Converter` annotation on the class as well as the `@Convert` annotation on the field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @RickS, we solved this issue.

PS: I solved this a long time ago, and experienced this issue again 2 years later. lol

The solution is in the converter: JpaDateConverter, when you convert a DateTime Objetivo to java.sql.Date, according to the docs:

> If the given milliseconds value contains time information, the driver
>   will set the time components to the time in the default time zone (the
>   time zone of the Java virtual machine running the application) that
>   corresponds to zero GMT.

So to fix this I changed the server timezone:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

And in MySQL:

```
SET @@global.time_zone = '+00:00';
```

Comment: This answer worked for me, I was inserting a date (eg `LocalDate.of(1961, 3, 15)`) and getting the previous day in the MySQL database (eg "1961-03-14"). Using the `SET` command fixed this for me.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

**Use [JPA 2.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API#JPA_2.2)** for its support of *java.time*.

Use a date-only class in Java to work with date-only values in SQL.

```
LocalDate                           // Represent a date-only, without a time-of-day and without a time zone.
.now(                               // Get today's date…
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )     // …as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region.
)                                   // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.plusMonths( 1 )                    // Returns another `LocalDate` object, per immutable objects pattern.
```

## *java.time*

[JPA 2.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API#JPA_2.2) now supports the modern *java.time* classes. No need to use Joda-Time anymore.

**Do *not* use `java.sql.Date`.** That class *pretends* to represent a date-only but actually has a time-of-day set to UTC because of the terrible design decision to inherit from `java.util.Date` (which despite the name represents a date *and* a time-of-day *and* an offset of zero for UTC itself). These legacy classes are an awful wretched mess. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community all gave up on theses classes years ago with the adoption of JSR 310, and so should you.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety). Ditto for [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html) & [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

### Date-time math

Apparently you want to start with one date and get one month later as a date range.

```
LocalDate monthLater = ld.plusMonths( 1 ) ;
```

## JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2, your JDBC driver is required to support some of the key *java.time* classes such as `LocalDate`.

### Date-range

Note the links below for *ThreeTen-Extra*. You may find the `LocalDateRange` class there to be handy if you do much work with date ranges.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).