# Wrong LocalDate stored with hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, thymeleaf, localdate

I'm trying to store inside the database the date of a restaurant booking but, even though the date I submit is correct, hibernate stores inside the database a date one day before the one I submitted. I don't know why... it's probably a timezone problem but I can't understand why... the date should not be affected by the timezones.

Here is my spring boot properties file:

```
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    mode: HTML5
    encoding: UTF-8
    cache: false
  jpa:
    database: MYSQL
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        locationId:
          new_generator_mappings: false
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        jdbc:
          time_zone: UTC
  datasource:
    driver:
      class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: username
    password: **********
```

I'm from Italy, so my timezone is this:

- GMT/UTC + 1h during Standard Time
- GMT/UTC + 2h during Daylight Saving Time

Currently we are UTC + 2h.

The object I'm storing is this one:

```
@Entity
public class Dinner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long dinnerId;

    private LocalDate date;
    ...
```

The controller I'm using to intercept the POST request is this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
@PostMapping
public String createDinner(@RequestParam(value="dinnerDate") String dinnerDate, Principal principal, Model model){
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dinnerDate, formatter);
        dinnerService.createDinner(date);
        return "redirect:/dinners?dinnerDate=" + dinnerDate;
}
```

Which calls the service method *createDinner* that call the Jpa method *save* to store the object.
I'm using thymeleaf to handle the html templates.
If I submit the date 30/6/2019 inside the database I get 29/6/2019. When I retrieve the Dinner object by date, if I insert 30/6/2019, I get the Dinner with the date 29/6/2019. So it seems that spring handle the date by itself in a weird way... considering some sort of timezone but I don't know how to disable or handle it. Any idea?

Comment: what is the column database type of the `date`? Also please add the code for `createDinner(LocalDate date)` method.
+ look here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476364/hibernate-with-java-8-localdate-localdatetime-in-database : "...So if you want an appointment of 9 AM, you should use a LocalTime or LocalDateTime recorded in a database column of type TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE... "

Comment: The type is DATE, as I said createDinner just calls save.

Comment: some more questions: did you check what is actually in database after you save the entity? And how do you retrieve the Dinner object?

Comment: As I said: "If I submit the date 30/6/2019 inside the database I get 29/6/2019" so yes I checked... that's the whole point!
I retrieve the dinner object by calling the JpaRepository method findById. But the problem is in the database... it saves a wrong day...

Comment: What MySQL version and connector are you using?  Are you also using a third-party connection pool?  This could be relevant: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71084

Comment: You can try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60906163/8536903 to set-up local correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do not need to define a format for the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd`. [LocalDate#parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) uses `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE` by default which means `LocalDate.parse("2020-06-29")` works without applying a format explicitly.
2. Since you already know that date-time in your time-zone is different from that in UTC, you should never consider just a date; rather you should consider both date and time e.g.  11:30 PM at UTC on 2020-06-29 will fall on 2020-06-30 in your time-zone. Therefore, the first thing you should do is to change the type of the field as `TIMESTAMP` in the database.
3. Once you have changed the type of the field to `TIMESTAMP`, change the method, `createDinner` as follows:

   ```
   LocalDateTime dinnerDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.parse(dinnerDate), LocalTime.of(0, 0, 0, 0));
   OffsetDateTime odt = dinnerDateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
   dinnerService.createDinner(odt);
   ```

   Then inside `DinnerService` (or `DinnerServiceDAO` wherever you have written the logic to insert/update record in the database):

   ```
   pst.setObject(index, odt);
   ```

   where `pst` represents the object of `PreparedStatement` and `index` represents the index (starting with `1`) of this field in your insert/update query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your time zone is : Europe/Italy ,  You have to set up your serverTimezone variable like this :

url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Europe/Italy

Answer (score 0):

same problem (and same country! :-) ).

I suspect that if hibernate or jpa are set with timezone `UTC`, while the machine is set with default timezone == `Europe/Rome` when a date is persisted, then it will be converted automatically from machine timezone to database timezone, which is not a bad feature if you have all dates stored in UTC format on the DB.

The problem happens when you convert the date before persisting: it gets converted twice. At least, this is my case.

Still looking for the best solution! In case I'll find one, then I'll add it later to the answer.

Comment: Have you find a solution? It seems to be a bug in my opinion: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=104822&thanks=4

Comment: Nope.. I did not work on that project anymore. But I was using PostgreSql, the link is on the mysql forum...it may relate, but I'm not that expert with Hibernate to tell!