# Spring boot JPA with MySql DB - mapping Dates ends in having wrong day (1 day off)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

currently I am facing a strange issue with Spring JPA : Whenever I try to map a date as Date only, it saves the day I want to save minus 1 day. E.g. saving 1st of Feb --> I have 31st of Jan in my DB.
As long as I am using DateTime, everything is ok. 
Example : 
MySQL time zone set to System
System is on UTC + 1
in connection URL, serverTimeZone is set to UTC and useLegacyDatetimeCode = true

```
@Entity
public class ZoneEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createDateTime;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDate createDate;

    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date temporalDate;

    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;

    private LocalDate localDate;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATE")
    private LocalDate localDateWithColumn;

    public ZoneEntity() {
        temporalDate = new Date();
        localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        localDate = LocalDate.now();
        localDateWithColumn = LocalDate.now();
    }
```

I'll then save a new entity like this :

```
service.save(new ZoneEntity());
```

If I execute this today (24.02.2020), I'll end up with the following

```
createDateTime : 24.02.2020 15:20:00  --> Correct (UTC)

createDate : 23.02.2020 --> day - -1

temporalDate : 24.02.2020 15:20:00 --> Correct (UTC)

localDate : 23.02.2020 --> day - 1

localDateTime : 24.02.2020 15:20:00 --> Correct (UTC)

localDateWithColumn : 23.02.2020 --> day - 1
```

So however I save the date only, it ends with the wrong day. Does anybody have any idea why this happens ?

**added:**

If I have a look in the hibernate logging, the issue seems to be on the MySQL side...

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        zone_entity
        (create_date, create_date_time, local_date, local_date_time, local_date_with_column, temporal_date, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-02-24 16:42:25.371 TRACE 19628 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [2020-02-24]
2020-02-24 16:42:25.374 TRACE 19628 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2020-02-24T16:42:25.365036900]
2020-02-24 16:42:25.375 TRACE 19628 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [DATE] - [2020-02-24]
2020-02-24 16:42:25.375 TRACE 19628 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2020-02-24T16:42:25.302181]
2020-02-24 16:42:25.375 TRACE 19628 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [DATE] - [2020-02-24]
2020-02-24 16:42:25.376 TRACE 19628 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Mon Feb 24 16:42:25 CET 2020]
2020-02-24 16:42:25.376 TRACE 19628 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [BIGINT] - [294]
```

added : if I try to insert via MySQL workbench with the values below (as the parameters from Hibernate look like), everything is ok (left out the timestamp to make it a bit shorter).

```
insert 
    into
        zone_entity
        (create_date, create_date_time, local_date, local_date_time, local_date_with_column,id) 
    values
        ('2020-02-24', '2020-02-24T22:03:13.842324', '2020-02-24', '2020-02-24T22:03:13.842324', '2020-02-24',99);
```

**added**:
I now changed time zone in DB URL to Europe/London --> everything works as it should. Changing to UTC or Europe/London --> both does not work !

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase?serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

Many thanks in advance !

Kind regards

Joern

Comment: Is it exactly 1 day or some hours? As far as I know it converts time to UTC.

Comment: It seems to be 1 day. So my system time is UTC+1, MySQL is on System, but I send in UTC. So all times are correct. Only if I send "date only", it is on 1 day before - which from my POV does not seems to be time zone related, because local time is only 1 hour from UTC. Also when I do the same insert as this afternoon, I still have 23.02.2020 in all the date fields.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';`  Also, I don't think MySQL likes the "T" in the middle.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938999/jpa-saving-wrong-date-in-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

Having you tried with the below parameter in spring yml?

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
       hibernate.jdbc.time_zone: Europe/Berlin
```

Comment: Hi Suraj, I did a workaround in the meantime, where I save as date/time and wrap to date only. But I'll have a try, will just need some days until I'm back on this. Thanks ! Joern